# Question about ordered group and its order ideal.

Tags: group-theory, c-star-algebras, ordered-groups

I am reading a book entitled An introduction to the classification of amenable C*-algebras.
It reads,

> Definition 3.3.1 An ordered group $(G,G_+)$ is an abelian group $G$ with a distinguished subsemigroup $G_+$ containing zero, called the positive cone of $G$ satisfying the properties

> (1) $G_+-G_+=G$ and

> (2) $G_+\cap (-G_+)=\{0\}$

> $G_+$ induces a partial ordering on $G$ by $x\leq y$ if $y-x\in G_+$. Also, we write $g<f$, if $g\leq f$ and $g\neq f$.

> An order ideal $I$ of an ordered group $(G,G_+)$ is a subgroup of $G$ such that $g\leq f$ for some $f\in I$ implies that $g\in I$.

Since $I$ is a subgroup, $0\in I$. So for every $g\in G_+$, $0-(-g)=g\in G_+$ implies $-g\in I$ and
$g\in I$. Eventually, $G=G_+-G_+\subset I$ and $G=I$.

I wonder if I misunderstood something or if the book is wrong.

Comment: It’s a bit outside my bailiwick, but I think that the definition should say that $I$ is an order ideal if $0\le g\le f\in I$ implies that $g\in I$. In other words, $I\cap G_+$ is downward closed.

Comment: It is hard to discern what was on Lin's mind because he does not use the concept of order ideal much in the book, except to interpret the notion of order unit in the very same Definition.  However, for that interpretation to work I think one indeed needs to see things according to @BrianM.Scott's comment.